# disable button or cursor wait icon while button click function runs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I have a button click function that loads and runs an SSIS package

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoSomething" runat="server" Text="TEST run SSIS" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('TEST-TEST-TEST')" 
    OnClick="btnDoSomething_Click" />
```

within the click function I've tried setting the cursor to wait, setting a label to a wait message, and even disabling the button clicked -- however, nothing seems to happen .. any thing that I do in the function only happens AFTER the function (loading and running SSIS package) completes.

I don't know that I really care HOW I let the end user know that the process is running (outside of, in IE the tab icon is a spinning ball "waiting for ..." message)

thanks in advance (and yes, I've searched and searched and tried and tried ... I'm betting that I'm missing something silly)

```
    protected void btnDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        Package pckg;
        Variables vars;

        string SSISPackagePath = @"c:\test.dtsx";

        lblTEST.Text = "please wait ...";
        btnDoSomething.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            app = new Application();
            pckg = app.LoadPackage(SSISPackagePath, null);
            vars = pckg.Variables;
            vars["PACKAGE_NAME"].Value = "test";

            pkgResults = pckg.Execute(null, vars, null, null, null);

            if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
                lblTEST.Text = "shebang - it worked! (" + pkgResults.ToString() + ")";
            else
                lblTEST.Text = "something not good happened... (" + pkgResults.ToString() + ")";
            grdTest.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblTEST.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        btnDoSomething.Enabled = true;
    }
```

**UPDATE: THANKS THANKS FOR THE HELP!!**

Because I needed the confirm I added a simple script

```
    function getConfirm() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to generate letters for all RELEASED campaigns?")) {
            showOverlay();
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

and changed the onClientClick to call it 
OnClientClick="return getConfirm();"

for IE I also added

```
filter: alpha(opacity = 40);
```

to the css so it would display the opacity correctly .

LOVE the overlay .. THANKS!! :)

Comment: `OnClientClick="this.disabled = true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Disable the button**

Define a javascript function, as follows. You have to return `true` or you server event will not fire:

```
function disabledMe(btn) {
    btn.disabled = "disabled";
    return true;
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoSomething" runat="server" Text="TEST run SSIS" 
   OnClientClick="disabledMe(this);"
   OnClick="btnDoSomething_Click" />
```

---

**Option 2: Use an overlay**

This technique, in my opinion, is better because it will prevent any interaction with the page while you server event is running.

Create a div which will be styled to serve as the overlay:

```
<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
```

This CSS class will do the trick:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .overlay {
        background-color: #000;
        cursor: wait;
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.4;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999998;
    }
</style>
```

And you will need to use javascript to control the overlay visibility:

```
<script>
    function showOverlay() {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";     
    }

    function hideOverlay() {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Use the `showOverlay` function with the button client side click:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoAnythingElse" runat="server"
            Text="TEST run SSIS" OnClientClick="showOverlay();"
            OnClick="btnDoAnythingElse_Click" />
```

And at the end of the server event, register a script to call the function to hide the overlay:

```
protected void btnDoAnythingElse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulates a long running process
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hideOverlay", "hideOverlay();", true);
}
```

Comment: hmmm .. well, I really like your idea of solution 2 .. bit I still really really need the confirm onClientClick piece -- any ideas how I can run both?

Comment: eureka!! TOTALLY GOLDEN NOW. I created a simple script to do the ask and hide and return -- THANKS!!!

Comment: Nope...that's really strange. Does the browser console show any errors?